# javascript conflict issue, I am not able to find what's wrong

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using date picker in my form using http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
using 1.9.1 jquery.js
But in this file I am getting error

```
TypeError: $.isPlainObject is not a function


if ( $.isPlainObject( value ) ) {
```

So what's going wrong. Please tell me

My index.php code is here

```
 <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jQuery UI CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


<!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field  -->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: try using $.noConflict();

Comment: That `if` is in a function? If not ... that `if` is loaded with `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Where is this code in which causes this error? is it in `script.js`?

Comment: No its give error in jquery-ui.js

Comment: I got error in http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js at 455 line

Comment: Here's the answer to your 'just deleted' question: http://jsfiddle.net/0zrx4p7z/

Answer (score 2):

If it really is a conflict, this should work:

```
(function($){
$(function(){

// run code here

});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of $ try to use jQuery, May be your problem get fixed

e.g. 
if ( jQuery.isPlainObject( value ) ) {

Because sometime when $ is override then this problem may occur.

Also check have you applied $.functionname() instead of $('id\class').functionname(); because $. sign applies the function to the whole jquery element which also cause Type-error issue sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isplainobject/)

Host objects (or objects used by browser host environments to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript) have a number of inconsistencies which are difficult to robustly feature detect cross-platform. As a result of this, $.isPlainObject() may evaluate inconsistently across browsers in certain instances.